# How to carryout this integration in python: when y(t)=integrate[f(t,y)]

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have the following integral to be carried out. Problem is, the result of the integration 'y' depends on the value of 'y' itself. Therefore there should be a feedback loop, between right hand side and the left hand side. Initial value of y is zero.

[Here f(U) is a Gaussian function of U, with a mean value and standard deviation being mu and sigma respectively.]

I can carryout a simplified version of the integration when there is no coupling between LHS and RHS. i.e., if I replace the 'mt-y' term by a constant value in the right hand side (see my code, which doesn't solve the actual problem of course).

But I don't understand how to do the actual one with the coupling present.

[image]

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def integrand_1(U,A,t,p,gamma,m,n,alpha,mu,sig):

    k=gamma*np.exp(-n*np.power(U/(m*p),alpha));

    g=1-np.exp(-np.power(t,n)*k);

    f=np.exp(-np.power(U - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)));

    return A*g*f


A=10;
n=2;
alpha=5
mu=2;
sig=0.4;
gamma=11.11e12
time = np.logspace(-8, -4, 100)



p=2.5;
m=1;
Ylist_P2_5 = []
for t in time:
    Y = quad(integrand_1, 0, np.inf, args=(A,t,p,gamma,m,n,alpha,mu,sig))
    Ylist_P2_5.append(Y[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogx(time, Ylist_P2_5, 'k-*', label='x=2.5')
legend = ax.legend(loc='best', shadow=True, fontsize='x-large')
plt.xlabel('log(t)', fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.ylabel('y', fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: First: are you sure, that the y is the same at both sides of the equation? If it is, you need to solve the equation for y before you can integrate y.

Comment: In general, this is probably more suited for math exchange than for stackoverflow.

Comment: Is there any initial value for y? and will y be provided in a feedback loop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that `k` is a constant an f(u) is actually not a function of u but of µ. Can you recheck your variables?

Comment: (mt-y) :/ how does it make k konstant? Its changing with value y.

Comment: Equation and the program are not the same right now. ;/

Comment: Looks to me to be some sort of an equation of decaying oscillation. @NoorJafri

Comment: Hi all,
I updated the description of the problem. Yes, it requires a feedback loop between left hand side and right hand side.

k is not a constant in the actual problem. I wrote the code by just putting a constant value. Cant come out with the code for varying k.

Comment: Just to be sure, y1 depends on y0 and y2 depends on y1?